# could not launch process: invalid magic number in record at byte 0x0 Delve Golang

Tags: go, magic-numbers, delve

Just got a:

```
could not launch process: invalid magic number in record at byte 0x0
```

When running on OSX after working fine for a while:

```
dlv debug main.go
```

reinstalled Delve, but still persists. What can it be?

Comment: Can you build your package correctly without delve? Without a reproducible example, there's not we can do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the name of the package, I changed it and worked. Delve should give a better error message for that case.

Previously I had a custom name for the package name. After changing it to `main` delve started to work again.

Comment: What about the name of the package? Was the folder name wrong, or the actual "package main" wrong, or what? Getting the same error.

Comment: The package was called "main" and everything worked fine.Then I changed it to "invitations", and the error started happening. Then I noticed that func main() was not being called because of the change in package name. I guess delve has nothing to run or something.